# How can I fed address as an input with other integer data in Machine Learning Algorithm to train the model?

Tags: machine-learning, encoding, classification, data-science, dimensionality-reduction

I have data from  different restaurants which have also address of the restaurants now I want to predict the food delivery timing based on the given data, now the restaurant address is one of the crucial data which I need to predict the food delivery timing, now my problem is the address is in string format so how do I handle this address to feed the data in the ML model.

Data sample-
[image]

Comment: How many unique addresses do you have? if that value is not too large, consider using "one hot encoding"

Comment: there are total 8000 columns there are many same address but I didn't count how many different addresses are there is there any way to count

Comment: if data is in panda's dataframe, [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html)

Comment: total 35 unique values

Comment: If I do one hot encoding my data will be huge any other option except one hot encoding